# Linux not working with Radeon Vega 8 GPU

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, amd, amdgpu

I have a laptop, an Acer Aspire 3 A315-41G-R6KL with an
integrated Radeon Vega 8 graphics card on a Ryzen 5 2500U
CPU and a discrete Radeon R535. This laptop was running
Windows 10 before me. But today I put an SSD on it with Fedora
37 installed, after 2-3 minutes after starting, the screen freezes
and stops responding, as does the keyboard. I tried the
following kernel versions 6.2, 6.1, 6.0, 5.19 (in most cases, the screen freezes immediately after the desktop appears). With the amdgpu
driver. I also tried to install a new version of fedora, but the
installer freezes right after the desktop is displayed. I also tried
installing Manjaro and Ubuntu, in both cases the screen
and keyboard freezes after a couple of minutes, Manjaro also
had frequent screen flashes. I saw several articles
while trying to find a solution to the problem, which
said that with this line of processors, Linux has problems. Is it
still relevant? And isn't there a single way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem on my computer.  Per my manufacturers forum you need to disable hardware acceleration. I don't know how to do this, but I hope this answer helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was able to fix my issues by going full xorg and installing all the amd drivers, as well as removing all other nvidia and intel drivers